# S3 - PutObject results in 403 - forbidden - public access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am confused by the S3 bucket privacy settings.

I have created a Bucket that blocks all public access and I have created an IAM user which has the permission `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

Then I use the `Access Key` and `Access Secret` of that IAM user to place objects in the bucket, but this fails as `PutObject` returns a 403-forbidden error. I don't understand why, because the user has the role to access S3 fully.

My bucket permissions looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**So now I have two questions:**

1. Did I forgot something to get this working?
2. I know it works when I enable public access - but what does that mean exactly? Can any S3 user access my bucket to download/upload/access the files in that bucket or only the user which is displayed in the ACL - which is currently only the owner of the bucket?

Thanks for clarification!

Comment: " IAM user to place objects in the bucket" - how do you place these objects? using AWS console, AWS CLI or SDK?

Comment: I think my ecommerce system uses the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify you how are placing an object in the bucket. Lets make an assumption here. Assume you want to use code to perform this task. Now assume you set your IAM creds in a file named credentials in C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows or ~/.aws/credentials on Linux, macOS, or Unix. Assume you setup you IAM user by following this doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html#getting-started_create-admin-group-console

(I suspect you have a wrong setting for IAM - check this doc)

You can upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket using this code (this is the Java example - but you can find other examples for different programming languages).

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
    
public class PutObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  PutObject <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - the object to upload (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - the path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String objectKey = args[1];
        String objectPath = args[2];

        System.out.println("Putting object " + objectKey +" into bucket "+bucketName);
        System.out.println("  in bucket: " + bucketName);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        String result = putS3Object(s3, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Tag information: "+result);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.main]
    public static String putS3Object(S3Client s3,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String objectKey,
                                     String objectPath) {

        try {

            Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
            metadata.put("myVal", "test");

            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .metadata(metadata)
                    .build();

            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

           return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Return a byte array
    private static byte[] getObjectFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: "You did not specify you how are placing an object in the bucket." -> What do you mean with this exactly?